# Wordpress - form submission wrongly redirects to homepage

Tags: wordpress, forms, permalinks

I'm facing a strange behavior here and i'd need your help.
I've developed a Wordpress theme and i'm trying to submit a form (specific search) in a page, but i'm redirected to homepage instead of staying on the current page and process the form submission.

Here is what i tried :

- `<form method="post">`
- `<form method="post" action="https://www.example.com/requests/"`
- `<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"`

Each time, the link/permalink is ok, and of course, the page exists because i'm on it.

The weirdest thing is that the permalink in the browser's address bar is ok too, but though it's *https://www.example.com/requests/* for instance, the page displayed is the homepage (and *requests* is not my homepage). And if i just refresh my browser's tab, it's the right page that is displayed and not the homepage anymore...

Note that i also tried to change and save my permalink structure, with no positive effect.
And my .htaccess file is the WP's default one.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution.
In my form, i was using a hidden field named "s" which is a reserved name for search queries in WP, and it messed up everything. I renamed this hidden field and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave out the action attribute, the form will be submitted to the document's address, i.e. the same page. Maybe this works.

Edit: forget about it... i haven`t seen your first try ;-)

Edit 2: what about:

```
echo 'https://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

Maybe there is something wrong with your permalinks.

Regards  Tom

Comment: Yeah, I m sorry. I haven`t seen this one. Let me think a bit about it.

Comment: About your Edit 2, the value is the right one but still redirected to homepage

Answer (score 0):

Check your form field make all fields comment the test your submit button if all ok remove comment from each input box and test form. when you get the culprit input box change its name maybe it's affected the form

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer, please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment. Please also look at see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer